# Apply LAG function until clause in Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I have the below table (Redshift)

| event | url | rank | flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| clic | url1 | 1 |  |
| view | url2 | 2 |  |
| view | url3 | 3 | ✓ |
| clic | url4 | 1 |  |
| view | url5 | 2 | ✓ |

I would like to add a column with the url of the last clic. I tried with LAG() function but I don't know the offset. Is there a way to apply LAG until the previous clic ?

| event | url | rank | flag | CASE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| clic | url1 | 1 |  |  |
| view | url2 | 2 |  |  |
| view | url3 | 3 | ✓ | url1 |
| clic | url4 | 1 |  |  |
| view | url5 | 2 | ✓ | url4 |

```sql
SELECT *,
CASE
   WHEN flag 
        AND event = 'view'
        AND LAG(event) OVER (ORDER BY rank) = 'clic'
        THEN LAG(url)  
END
FROM myTable;
```

Comment: Please provide more context. It's hard to tell what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: some question or else its tough, is event = 'clic' ranks as always 1 ?  is flag = true means from the next row rank will again start from 1 ?  ley say rank (1, 2, 3) are a group, second rank (1, 2) are also a group....can such two groups collide ??

Answer (score 0):

This reads like a gaps-and-islands problem, where you want to show the url of the last gap (a click) at the end of each island of views.

We can use the cumulative count of clicks to define groups that start with a click, and then recover the url of the unique click in each group :

```
select t.*,
    case when flag and event = 'view' then
        max(case when event = 'click' then url end)
            over(partition by grp order by id)
    end url_click
from (
    select t.*,
        sum(case when event = 'click' then 1 else 0 end) 
            over(order by id) grp 
    from mytable t
) t
```

Note that this requires a column to sort rows on the whole table - which I called `id`.